Change labeling font color for different unique values in the same label class using ArcGIS Pro
First of all I am very new to ArcGIS Pro and it's my first GIS software.
I'm aware you can change the symbol for unique values in a label class, but can you change the color of the labeling so that it's different for each unique value? Because it's all the same label class so I try to change the labeling color for only one unique value in a field but then it changes it for all the unique values.

You want every possible combination of values to have a different colour?

With the layer selected in the Drawing Order tab, select the Labeling menu. THere is a Class dropdown menu item called, "Create label classes from symbology..." A dialog box will pop up with a class for each unique value in the field. Pick the appropriate options.
The Class dropdown menu will now have more entries. For each entry, highlight it, then change the symbol colour in the "Text Symbol" part of the ribbon.
